# how to set color of text in selected TextView

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How to set color of text in selected TextView.

i try it not able to figure it out.

Is it possible to change UITextView`s color in particular range ?

Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
NSString *selection = [textView.text substringWithRange:textView.selectedRange];
```

Comment: Thanks A lot .... Actually i need to set textColor for selected String in UITextView.